# validation of the entered field

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, currency

in my application, I enter the values of the three parameters, `fromCurrency`, `toCurrency`, and `amount` into the address bar
and in the controller. I want to check the correctness of the entered data. But I have generated an exception during the test and nothing goes further
Those. I need a code that in the controller will check the correctness of the entered data and, depending on the field in which the error was made, will produce a 400th error with the name of the incorrectly filled field

I'm tried this validation, with

```
if(!Currency.getAvailableCurrencies().contains(Currency.getInstance(fromCurrency)))
```

but it's generate exception if Currency doesn't contain fromCurrency

```
@RestController
class ExchangeController {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ExchangeController.class.getName());

    @SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiredFieldsWarningInspection")
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataService")
    private CurrencyExchangeService currencyExchangeService;

    @SuppressWarnings("SameReturnValue")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public String start() {
        return "input parameters";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/convert", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public ExchangeRateDTO converting(@RequestParam("fromCurrency") String fromCurrency,
                                      @RequestParam("toCurrency") String toCurrency,
                                      @RequestParam("amount") String amount) throws IOException {
        if (!Currency.getAvailableCurrencies().contains(Currency.getInstance(fromCurrency))) {

        }
        BigDecimal convertedAmount = currencyExchangeService.convert(fromCurrency, toCurrency, new BigDecimal(amount));
        return new ExchangeRateDTO(fromCurrency, toCurrency, new BigDecimal(amount), convertedAmount);
    }
}
```

Comment: Change your `fromCurrency` and `toCurrency` from `String` to `Currency` and `amount` to `BigDecimal`. Spring will do the conversion or an exception if it cannot convert. If you really want to stick with `String` (which I would advice against) , use a form object and write a `Validator` to do the validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Hibernate Validator to validate the `@RequestParam` of your controller.

Add this dependency to your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you have to enable validation for both request parameters and path variables in your controllers by adding the `@Validated` annotation like this

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
@Validated
public class Controller {
    // ...
}
```

Then you can add Annotations like `@NotNull` `@Min` `@Max` to your RequestParam Like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/convert", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public ExchangeRateDTO converting(@RequestParam("fromCurrency") @NotNull @NotBlank @Size(max = 10) String fromCurrency,
                                      @RequestParam("toCurrency") String toCurrency,
                                      @RequestParam("amount") String amount) throws IOException {
        if (!Currency.getAvailableCurrencies().contains(Currency.getInstance(fromCurrency))) {

        }
        BigDecimal convertedAmount = currencyExchangeService.convert(fromCurrency, toCurrency, new BigDecimal(amount));
```

You can also define custom annotations for your needs.

There is more detailed and nice article [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-validate-requestparam-pathvariable)